# Remove Account Deletion from Profiles

Tags: profile, account, delete

I'm trying to edit user profiles to not allow account deletion in SalesForce. Whenever I edit the profiles and uncheck the Account deletion checkbox and save it, it doesn't save. How are you suppose to make it where only certain profiles are able to delete accounts. I can't have random users deleting Accounts. Also these are custom profiles and not standard.

Thanks!

EDIT: It will implement the change in the production environment but not in the test environment. Does anyone know why?

Comment: are you checking modify all on the user profile after unchecking the delete on account for the profile

Comment: no... why would I do that?

Comment: well thats the only way system auto populates delete option for all objects hence the above question

Comment: oh, right. It's allowing me to uncheck the delete option in production but not in the test environment. when I uncheck it in the test environment and save it, it goes back to being checked. And it seems like I'm the only one to experience this because I can't find any thread with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

To change user details—such as a user’s profile, role, or contact information—.“Manage Internal Users” permission is needed following link will be helpfull:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=editing_users.htm&language=en_US